# How can I interact with a third-party web page using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, automation

My company has a JavaScript-heavy (Backbone-based) web site living at an external domain which I have no control over. I'd like to automate some tasks. Basically I want to click on some things, fill out some form fields, and submit a button. However, I also want the ability to do logic tests and enter different values in fields based on various states of things in the page.

I know I can probably use Selenium for this, but are there any alternatives? Maybe a pure JavaScript solution?

For instance, if I could do this, it would be great:

```
$('#someButton').click();

if (parseInt($('#someDiv').text()) > x) {
    $('#someField').val(123);
    someCounter++;
}

$('#submitButton').click();
```

Even if I could inject custom JavaScript into the web page...that could work too.

Comment: Hi Chad. In general, commentary about voting is not all that valuable here, since voters do not hang about to read and respond to such enquiries. Editors here generally remove that sort of material from questions anyway, since future readers outnumber voters by a wide margin, and to them it isn't of interest.

Comment: If you want to avoid Selenium, another approach is to use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/). You can drive this directly using JavaScript, and there are bound to be libraries that make this process easier still (I've used it via a PHP driver for functional testing, and it is very reliable).

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with selenium using pure Js.
basically you'll need the WebDriverJs.

Here some code example.

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

var driver = new webdriver.Builder().
   withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).
   build();

driver.get('http://www.google.com');
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('q')).sendKeys('webdriver');
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('btnG')).click();
driver.wait(function() {
 return driver.getTitle().then(function(title) {
   return title === 'webdriver - Google Search';
 });
}, 1000);

driver.quit();
```

More information here
https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a bookmarklet. Basically I wrote pure JavaScript, transformed it into a bookmarklet using http://ted.mielczarek.org/code/mozilla/bookmarklet.html, and now I can click the bookmark when I visit the page. Voila.